# Python threading: how to make concurrent objects

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to learn how to use Python threading, can anyone help with this confusing parts.

Let's consider this example; Let's supposed that we have 3 groups of workers in a company, the workers are completing tasks. We want to affect tasks to these groups in a way that we optimize the choice.

I tried to build a threading object for group of workers, so they have

```
class GroupOfWokers:
    def __init__(self, n, q,c):
        self.name= n
        self.q= 0 # number of tasks that we can do // self.q=Queue()
        self.capacity= c

    def giveTask(self):
        #for the second suggestion self.q.put(i)
        if self.q<self.capacity: 
          self.q+=1
          return true
        else:
          return false

    def tasks(self):
       # how many tasks are you working on 
        return self.q
```

in the main program

```
g1,g2,g3= GroupOfWokers('G-1',0,9), GroupOfWokers('G-2',0,5), GroupOfWokers('G-3',0,6)
```

Now, I need to know how can I make them working on a concurrent way.

- How can I make everyone working on a thread ?
- How can I make shared variables between these threads ? (in this case, how many tasks the whole team is working on, true it can be done by summing up the groups tasks after extracting the values using tasks(), but I need to understand the process of a shared variable between different threads ).
- When should I use queue() and when I don't. In case of `self.q= 0 # number of tasks that we can do // self.q=Queue()` should I just use incremental variable or should I use queue(). What is the benifit ?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is probably due to the current design.

What you probably want is a `Worker` class that extends the [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) class, and has a [`run`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run) method (which enables you to use [`Worker.start`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) on each instance to start it), and a [`Queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) instance that they all consume from.

**Edit** - here is a simple example:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 10
NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 1000

# create tasks
tasks = ['task %d' % i for i in range(NUMBER_OF_TASKS)]

class Worker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, name, queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.task_queue = queue
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            if not task == "stop":
                print "%s working on %s" % (self.name, task)
            else:
                print "%s is stopping" % self.name
                break

if "__main__" == __name__:

    queue = Queue()

    workers = [Worker("Worker %d" % i, queue) for i in range(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS)]

    for task in tasks:
        # put tasks in queue
        queue.put(task)

    for worker in workers:
        # start workers
        worker.start()

    for worker in workers:
        # stop workers
        queue.put("stop")

    for worker in workers:
        # wait for workers
        worker.join()
```

Comment: Can you show some code based on the given example. I can't see exactly what do you mean ?

Comment: Thnaks! neat code. Is queue = Queue() a shared variable (like a shared pool), so that self.task_queue.get() can get tasks from it. Why do you use worker.join() to wait ?

Comment: `Thread.join` is the standard way to reflect that you're waiting for the threads to end their run before proceeding. We have everything `Thread` offers since we've extended it, so why not use it?

Comment: last question, is it doable to affect specific task (let's say a task in the middle), or queue() is the implementation of a queue concept last in, first out. Imagine it as a basket of taskets and I am giving tasks to workers based on the reference of tasks (I prioritize tasks based on their importance and their length). I am not asking to implement, jsut a guidnace if this is doable or no, in case I need to digg into other thing or no

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue , also, if you have a mutable object as a task you can change it's state. If it's immutable you probably want a **result queue** to report newly created results as well, or some other shared object.

Comment: If i need to access to fields of worker, let's say [x.name for x in workers if x[-1]=='1'] , how can I do that, and what is the best practice here